# WordPressの使用可否の判断について。

Tags: wordpress

世界的にWebシステムにはWordPressを取り入れているシステムが多いと知ったのですが
新しいWebシステムを開発するときWordPressの使用可否の判断はどのような点にあるのでしょうか。
ホームページを作成するときは大概WordPressを使用するなどあるのでしょうか。

Comment: > `Webシステム` とは具体的にどのようなものを想定していますか？記載されている通り、ホームページのような比較的静的なものでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

ホームページの更新は自分自身で行うのでしょうか？
HTMLでホームページを作成した場合、更新のたびにFTPで送信する必要があります。
WordPressの場合、一度サイトを作成した後は、サイトにアドミニストレータ等でログインし、
文章を書き換えることができます。＊できない部分もあります。
従いまして、更新を他の人にやってもらう場合や、外出先等で更新する場合はWordPressの方が楽です。
ただ、最初の設定はデータベースの設定やPHP等が絡んでくるため、HTMLで書いた場合より面倒になります。
また、WordPressを使う場合、サーバーが対応していなければいけません。
無料サーバー等では対応していない場合もあります。
このメリット、デメリットを考慮して選択すればいいかと思います。